# Can't get to 4096x1440 resolution

Tags: linux, display, intel-graphics, resolution

I'm trying to set up a X220 ThinkPad (Intel HD 3000) with a 5120x1440 monitor. For some reason I can't figure out there seems to be a limit where I can't reach 4096x1440.

For reference, I'm using the following script:

```
TEST_MONITOR=DP3

LINE=$(cvt $@ | grep -Po '(?<=Modeline ).*')
xrandr --newmode $LINE --verbose
SHORTLINE=$(echo "$LINE" | grep -Po "^[^ ]*")
xrandr --addmode $TEST_MONITOR $SHORTLINE --verbose
xrandr --output $TEST_MONITOR --mode $SHORTLINE --verbose
```

For some reason I can get it running with 4088x1440@44fps, 4080x1440@44fps and 4088x1440x30fps, but I cannot get it to run at 4096x1440@30fps, which makes me think it's not a bandwidth issue.

xrands reports that I have a lot of margin left:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5454 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767 (Monitors placed horizontally)
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4088 x 2208, maximum 32767 x 32767 (Monitors places vertically)
```

When trying to set a bigger resolution I get the following in my Xorg.log:

```
[ 77786.820] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 5462x1440
[ 77786.899] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 4096x1440@30.0 on DP1 using pipe 1, position (1366, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 77786.919] (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument [22]
[ 77787.275] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 5454x1440
[ 77787.277] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.1 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 77787.758] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 4088x1440@44.0 on DP1 using pipe 1, position (1366, 0), rotation normal, reflection none

[ 77795.738] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 6486x1440
[ 77795.863] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 5120x1440@30.0 on DP1 using pipe 1, position (1366, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 77795.883] (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument [22]
[ 77796.215] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 5454x1440
[ 77796.217] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.1 on LVDS1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 77796.745] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 4088x1440@44.0 on DP1 using pipe 1, position (1366, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
```

I've also checked that it should not be a framebuffer issue, with the following xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 10574 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 280mm x 160mm
   1366x768      60.10*+
   1280x720      59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   "4080x1440_44.00"  43.99  
   "4088x1440_44.00"  43.99  
DP2 connected 4088x1440+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1190mm x 340mm
   4088x1440     43.99*+
   5120x1440     29.96  
   4080x1440     29.97  
   3840x1080     59.97  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2560x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080    120.00   100.00   119.88    60.00    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   "4080x1440x29.97"  29.97  
   "4080x1440x29.96"  59.92  
   "4088x1440x29.97"  29.97  
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 connected 5120x1440+5454+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   "5120x1440_60.00"  59.96* 
VIRTUAL2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I've tried running with and without framebuffer compression, I've tried to run the kernel with nomodeset, I've tried DRI 2 and 3, I've tried different acceleration methods.

I'm running out of ideas. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did the resolution you are trying to set already work under a different OS?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really have a way of checking that, at least not right now.